# Validate multiple form with one javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a page that has 6 forms that all have a value with the same name 'audit_id_upload'.  Currently I have one of them being validated (I'm just looking for empty values) with...

```
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["audit_upload"]["audit_id_upload"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please Select an Audit");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Can I adapt this to validate the other forms as well without having to repeat it 5 more times?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have a input element with `audit_id_upload` in every form, you could pass the name of your form to this function and use it to validate the item.

```
function validateForm(fName)
{
   var x=document.forms[fName]["audit_id_upload"].value;
   if (x==null || x=="")
   {
      alert("Please Select an Audit");
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

and call it on the for onSubmit event.

```
<form name='f1' onsubmit="return validateForm('f1')">

</form>

<form name='f2' onsubmit="return validateForm('f2')">

</form>

<form name='f3' onsubmit="return validateForm('f3')">

</form>
```

Comment: Gah! Beat me to it. I was about to offer the same solution. A good solution nonetheless :)

Comment: Brill, I was using the onsubmit but I was thinking that I somehow had to have a reference for every form name in the script, didn't think to pass the value like that, thanks!

Comment: Nice guys. I hope it help you, and remember to check the anwser as a anwser to help other users with the same problem and improve the SO website. :)

Comment: nice solution, but maybe you can just pass "this" to the function, so the function doesn't need to redo the search to the form. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(theform)
    {
        if (theform.thefield.value == "foo") return true;
        else return false;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
        <form action="" onsubmit="return test(this);">
        <input type="text" value="" name="thefield" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <form action="" onsubmit="return test(this);">
        <input type="text" value="" name="thefield" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <form action="" onsubmit="return test(this);">
        <input type="text" value="" name="thefield" />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```